# Installing .sty package for Texstudio on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: packages, texstudio, installing, ubuntu

How to install a .sty package that is missing when a tex file is being built by Texstudio for Ubuntu 20.04? Any method would work for me, but preferably a method via terminal or preamble of the tex file would be the most useful.

Comment: You don't install packages in TeXStudio!. TexStudo is an editor. You need to install the package into your latex installation. For that we need to know exactly what LaTeX you use? Since you are on Ubuntu, you either installed via the Ubuntu package manager (in that case use `apt-file` to figure out which Ubuntu package provide this latex package). If you installed LaTeX by hand (from tug.org/texlive) then you should already have all latex packages but in case you installed a minimal installation you can use `tlmgr` to install packages.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder @daleif - for some reason I forgot the separate latex installation. I installed texlive-latex-recommended but still get the error saying that mathcomp.sty package is missing.

Comment: I just had a look on that package, that seems to be units, use the `siunitx` package insteads, that is the standard now. Much has changed since 2001 when `mathcomp` was last updated.

Comment: Besides according to my ubuntu 18.04 (via `apt-file`, remember to run `sudo apt-file update`) `mathcomp.sty` is in `texlive-science`. Note that this splitting into many Ubuntu packages is why I use upsteam TeXLive and can thus install individual packages using `tlmgr`

Comment: Thanks @daleif , it solved the problem! You can formulate it as an answer for this question :)

Comment: Which of them??

Comment: @daleif the first one where you mention that I should install latex packages (I did by ```texlive-latex-recommended``` ) and the one where you mention ```mathcomp.sty``` is part of  ```texlive-science``` (I also got this info by googling - you commented quite fast!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of `mathcomp` seems to just provide some symbols to write units. Nowadays the latex standard is to use the `siunitx` package instead.

Regarding `mathcomp` and `texlive-latex-recommended` from Ubuntu. Ubuntu splits TeXLive into several Ubuntu packages (not to be confused with LaTeX packages, they often contain many latex packages). Given that `mathcomp` is not a widely used package it is unlikely that it is listed in `texlive-latex-recommended`, might be easier to just install it all `texlive-all` I think it is called(?)

Personally I don't use TeXLive from Ubuntu as I'd like to get the latest updates so I use the upstream one (see http://tug.org/texlive).

If you use Ubuntu and the TeXLive that Ubuntu provides the way you figure out which Ubuntu package a given latex package belongs to is to make sure you have `apt-file` installed

```
sudo apt install apt-file
sudo apt-file update
```

Run the latter command from time to time.

Then search a latex package via for example

```
apt-file search mathcomp.sty
```

and here it tells me

```
texlive-science: /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathcomp/mathcomp.sty
```

so I would need to install `texlive-science`